# Update Modal Window Content Without Closing and Re-Opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

This is my first post on here ever so if I'm not following protocol forgive me.

I have a modal window that opens and displays details about a record upon opening. I use AJAX and Javascript to retrieve and set those values in the modal window. Inside that modal window I also have some forms which allow a user to update details such as status about that record. Everything works properly, but I'd like to figure out how to update elements in the modal window without having to close and reopen it.

Example: I open the modal window to view the details on a record. I see the status is currently "Open". I then use form to change status to "Pending". I want the status element to update to "Pending" without having to close modal window.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is closing and opening the modal window the only way.

```
<!-- MODAL DETAILS ABOUT RECORD -->
<div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">DETAILS</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- FORMS TO ADD COMMENT, CHANGE STATUS, CHANGE CRITICAL RATING. THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO UPDATE THE MODAL WITHOUT CLOSING, SAY I ADD A COMMENT I WOULD LIKE IT TO ADD A ROW TO MY DYNAMIC TABLE BELOW, OR CHANGE THE STATUS I WANT THE STATUS TO UPDATE DOWN BELOW IN THE OBSERVATION DETAILS AREA -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <form class="form-inline" action=javascript:createNewComment() method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="newcomment">Comment</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="existingguid" class="form-control" id="existingguid" />
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newcomment" name="newcomment" placeholder="New Comment">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <form class="form-inline" action=javascript:updateRating() method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="updateRating" class="form-control" id="updateRating">
                                <option value=" ">Choose Rating</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Rating</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <form class="form-inline" action=javascript:updateStatus() method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="updateStatus" class="form-control" id="updateStatus">
                                <option value=" ">Update Status</option>
                                <option>Pending</option>
                                <option>Deferred</option>
                                <option>Closed</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Status</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- OBSERVATION DETAILS POPULATED DYNAMICALLY -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h4 class="text-center">OBSERVATION</h4>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Rating:</label>
                            <p class="form-control-static" name="rating" id="rating"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Status:</label>
                            <p class="form-control-static" name="status" id="status"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- COMMENTS TABLE BUILT DYNAMICALLY -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h4 class="text-center">COMMENTS</h4>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered" id="COMMENTS"></table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some code examples of what you have in place?

Comment: You are using a form post which means that when you return from the server it will go to a new page.  If you don't want that then you should use ajax instead.

Comment: I will have to investigate how to do that, but I'm sure I can find plenty of examples. Once I post my forms via ajax how do I go about updating my modal elements?